# C# windows forms child window creation with VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let's say I have a basic form, there's a button and when I click it, it opens a new window. 
How can I do this? I tried creating a new form instance on button click event, but it gives me exception, that something is wrong.

Comment: show your code please.  What is the exception?

Comment: Sorry, I would show the exception but I don't remember what I was doing that caused it and I can't reproduce it now!

Comment: Bah, I can't remember the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.ShowDialog();
//frm.Show();
```

Or please share your code..

Comment: That was so easy... Thanks! By the way, could you tell me a good page to learn c sharp (windows forms especially), if you know one? I tried searching but I really couldn't find any decent ones. :(

Comment: Google is your friend, trust me :) something like http://www.google.com/search?q=start+learning+C%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming that ur first form is named Form1 and ur second form is Form2

//assuming that ur button is button1
//inside form1 something like this is shown
Button1.Click +=  new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);

void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){
Form2 form = new Form2();
//you do either
Form2.Show();
//or focus remains on form2 do this
Form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

//hope this help